# Persist multi entity form in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to persist data from a multi entity form.

Here is the ClearType

```
<?php

namespace IS\ClearBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ClearType extends AbstractType
{
     public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date','date', array(
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'choice',
    ))
        ->add('urlStatus', 'choice',array('choices' => array('Done' => 'Done','Not Done' => 'Not Done'),'required' => false))

         ->add('applicationStatus', 'choice',array('choices' => array('Done' => 'Done','Not Done' => 'Not Done'),'required' => false))

        ->add('project','entity',array('class'=>'IS\ClearBundle\Entity\Project', 'property'=>'name'))

    ;
}
```

Here the Controller:

```
  public function updateAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('ISClearBundle:Clearance')->find($id);

        $project = $em->getRepository('ISClearBundle:Project')->find($entity->getProjectId());



        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Clear entity.');
        }

        $editForm   = $this->createForm(new ClearType(), $entity);


        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $editForm->bindRequest($request);


        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clear_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

The project is referenced in the Clear entity:

```
    <?php

    namespace IS\ClearBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * IS\ClearBundle\Entity\Clear
     */
    class Clear
    {
        /**
         * @var datetime $date
         */
        private $date;

        /**
         * @var string $urlStatus
         */
        private $urlStatus;

        /**
         * @var string $applicationStatus
         */
        private $applicationStatus;

        /**
         * @var string $ipStatus
         */
        private $ipStatus;

        /**
         * @var string $totalStatus
         */        
        private $totalStatus;

        /**
         * @var integer $id
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var IS\ClearBundle\Entity\Project
         */
        private $project;
```

I don't have an idea how to persist the project ID in the form.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The declaration of the field `project` in your form type lets the user change the `project` assigned to the `$entity`, so you're not altering the `$project` itself anywhere. Why do you want to persist the `$project`?

Comment: I want to save the assigned project id in the entity, which doesen't work. In the form I show the project name as nobody knows the ID, but the name of the associated project. Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: This should happen automatically, as long as you have your Doctrine Mapping (I assume you are storing it in `xml` or `yaml` files since there are no annotations for Doctrine ORM in your entity) configured correctly. Perhaps you should set the `data_class` attribute in your form type to `IS\ClearBundle\Entity\Clear` via the `setDefaultOptions` method to tell Symfony that you are actually trying to edit an entity. See http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes